# How can I somehow "store" a json file in a Spring-Boot program so my web app then reads this json

Tags: java, json, spring-boot

Basically, I'm writing my first Spring-Boot program, and I have to get a list of products stored on a JSON file to display each product using VueJS (I know how to use Vue, I just need to get the JSON data somewhere in the webpage or smth)

I spent last 3'5 hours looking at tutorials about consuming JSON's and POST stuff and none helped.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and include the Spring Boot code you have tried and that does not work as intended.

Comment: Please share more details with related code with a specific issue.

Comment: It's not that I tried a code and it didnt work, simply none of the tutorials I've readed/watched did what I want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets call your file config.json.

In a typical maven project, keep your file at

```
src/main/resources/config.json
```

In your code, read it like

```
    try {

        ClassPathResource configFile = new ClassPathResource("config.json");

        String json = IOUtils.toString(configFile.getInputStream(), Charset.forName(Util.UTF_8));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        String errMsg = "unexpected error while reading config file";
        logger.error(errMsg, e);
        throw new Exception(e);
    }
```

After this, use Jackson or GSON to read the json into an object. From there you can either reference it directly as a static attribute or as an attribute in component as per your use case.

Comment: Ok! I will try it now!

Comment: Ok now I have all the JSON in a variable. Now how do I turn it into a static element and where do I have to reference it so it works with Vue?

Comment: That'll take a few steps. I suggest
1. Use an ObjectMapper to convert the string to an Object
2. Use Spring-boot-web to expose an endpoint that Vue.js can call. Have a look at this tutorial for an idea - https://dzone.com/articles/building-your-first-spring-boot-web-application-ex

Answer (score 0):

Hope this code will work for you

```
public class JsonReader{
    public static void readFromJson() throws Exception {
        InputStream inStream = JsonReader.class.getResourceAsStream("/" + "your_config_file.json");
        Map<String, String> keyValueMap =
                new ObjectMapper().readValue(inStream, new TypeReference<Map<String, String>>() {});
        inStream.close();
    }
}
```

You might need to add the maven dependency for ObjectMapper()